# Importing data from database into a dropdown list in my view using ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to bring data from my database and show it in a dropdownlist in my webpage:
The returned data will have two parameters: DisciplineID and DisciplaneName.

Everything works proper until the Controller. It returns proper data but need help on how to move the data to the view properly.

Here is the breakdown of my project using MVC5:

**Model Class:**

```
public class Discipline
{
    public int DisciplineID { get; set; }
    public string DisciplineName { get; set; }
}
```

**Model Class Implementation:**

```
    public class DisciplineModel : IDiscipline
    {
            private List<Discipline> disciplinesList = new List<Discipline>();

            public IEnumerable<Discipline> disciplines()
            {
                LoadDisciplines(); //populates disciplinesList from database
                return disciplinesList;

            }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditDiscipline()
    {
        var disciplinesList = _idiscipline.disciplines();
        return View(disciplinesList);
    }
```

Data is brought upto here, but need to move that data to the View.

**View:**

```
@model OnlineTestingSystem.Models.Discipline
<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditDiscipline", "Discipline", FormMethod.Post))
    {

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.DisciplineName, "Discipline Name")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.DisciplineID, Model.disciplines,"Selected")
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
    }
    @ViewBag.message
</div>
```

I need to add the data returned from the dropdownlist to show The DisciplineIDs. So How do I modify my different classes to achieve this goal?

The syntax of the line below is not proper, I just wanted to show that this is what I am trying to do.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.DisciplineID, Model.disciplines,"Selected")
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a ViewModel that holds the list and the selected `id` of this list:

```
public class DisciplineViewModel
{

    public int? DisciplineId {get; set;}
    public List<Discipline> DisciplineList  {get ; set;}
}
```

then initialize this view model in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditDiscipline()
{
    var disciplinesList = _idiscipline.disciplines();
    var vm = new DisciplineViewModel
     {
           DisciplineList  = disciplinesList;
     }
    return View(vm);
}
```

then in the view :

```
 @model OnlineTestingSystem.Models.DisciplineViewModel
 <div class="container">
 @using (Html.BeginForm("EditDiscipline", "Discipline", FormMethod.Post))
 {

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DisciplineList)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DisciplineId, new SelectList(Model.DisciplineList , "DisciplineID ", "DisciplineName "),  "Select..." )
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
 }
@ViewBag.message
```

Comment: By adding DisciplineList to DisciplineViewModel, its breaking SOLID principles, how would you change this to be consistent with SOLID?

Comment: View Model is just for viewing data, it has nothing to do with the system architecture, you only use it to pass data from the controller to the view and vice versa

Comment: Thanks @cyber progs, this put me in the right direction.